# How to get a brown/burned texture on cornbread?

Tags: baking

I am using the [recipe here](http://www.bonappetit.com/recipe/easy-savory-cornbread) to make oven baked cornbread. The image in the recipe shows a nice [brown/burned texture](http://www.bonappetit.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/easy-savory-cornbread-940x560.jpg). I was wondering if I have to brush the top with butter or egg to get that texture?

What I ended up with is a pale yellow top layer with no browning or burned texture. Like the top layer of [this one](http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/d21/unsecured/media/1033249144001/1033249144001_2407513184001_video-still-for-video-2385004321001.jpg?pubId=1033249144001).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you just need to turn up the heat a bit. Moving the rack higher might help too.

It's a little hard to say without actually measuring your oven, but that kind of thing can happen if your oven's just a bit cooler than it claims to be. So it'll take a little longer than the recipe says to bake, but the lower temperature means it won't brown as nicely. Turning up the heat will get more browning done by the time the center's done.